# TypeInitializationException thrown for Program class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

My Windows Forms application was working earlier, however suddenly it stopped working. I am getting following exception:

[image]

With exception details as follows:

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>       Additional information: The type initializer for 'NotificationTester.Program' threw an exception.

When I click OK, the VS windows then shows following:

[image]

The solution was working fine earlier. I don't get whats going wrong.

Comment: for `TypeInitializationException` you need to check the InnerException property for more details

Comment: Well I know I should look for InerExceotion whenever exception occurs by clicking on Exception Details link on the Exception pop up dialog box as shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ypX7x.png). Point is my code does not enter `Program.Main()` So I am not able to debug my code. I hit F5 and get this  exception. And unfortunately this exception dialog does not have View Details link. So I think down vote on this question will be removed.

Comment: Ohh its `static Program()` constructor as well recognized by @Marc Gravell below, wish the exception description could have told me that.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

So: either one of the field-initializers, or the static constructor, for `Program` - is failing. Find out why. Note: the `InnerException` has the actual exception that was raised, but basicaly: just debug the field initializers and static constructor. So look inside the `Program` class for either:

```
static SomeType someField = /* some non-trivial expression or method call */
```

or:

```
static Program() {
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Another possible reason: the app.config has duplicate sections.

Comment: Yip, had the same issue. 
Was duplication in app.config (bad copy paste).
Had applicationSettings tag duplicated.
  `<applicationSettings>
    <applicationSettings>
      <MyProject.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="xxxx" serializeAs="String">
          <value>....</value>
        </setting>
      </MyProject.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
.....
</applicationSettings>`

Comment: That was it for me too!  I checked my source control history and saw a change.  I removed the change and all is well now.  We'll need to throw @Stagg a party.

Comment: I had this problem when I added an `<appSettings>` element to a config that was already using `<applicationSettings>`

Answer (score 9):

A possible reason: init a **static** dictionary with duplicated keys.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error message and for my case the reason is my main program is set to build as 32 bit console app and I added a private variable logger which access a 64bit dll.

```
public class Program
{
    public static readonly Logger logger = new Logger(typeof(Program));
```

After I changed the main program to be build as 64bit, the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the reason was, that `<configSections>` wasn't first one in `config` file.

> Only one `<configSections>` element allowed per
>    config file and if present must be the first child of the root  `<configuration>` element.

Move the `configSections` element to the top in your config file.

Hope it helps to someone.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a very silly thing. I had accidentally typed something like this

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
         <add key="someKey" value="SomeValue" />sss
         <add key="someKey1" value="SomeValue1" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

sss - Caused the error for me. Any random character entry.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error with platform target set as any CPU and prefer 32-bit checked, unchecking that last one solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is one weird issue I had to deal with for the last 2 hours. I solved it by removing the static from the lists I created.

```
private static readonly List<Person> someList = GlobalConfiguration.Connection.PopulateList();
```

with this one:

```
private readonly List<Person> someList = GlobalConfiguration.Connection.PopulateList();
```

Hope it helps and you don't have to spend two hours to find out the bug...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not missing any dependency DLLs. In my case, a DLL I was referencing had a dependency on another DLL.

If this is what happened, look at the "Inner Exception" property and then you will see a better error message. In my case, it said "Cannot find xxx.dll"

Answer (score 1):

So, If you didn't get an innerException message like me, you can set a breakpoint on some of the static variables like strings that you may have declared. Then you can debug forwards from there with F10.

Comment: This was it. I usually set all my globals on top, and always initialize them in the constructor. Lately I've been changing it up, and forgot to check there first.

Answer (score 0):

This issue for me was caused by a rogue user.config file that was created in the AppData\Local[Manufacturer][Product Name] directory.  I'm not sure how it got there, but seems to be created every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all of the answers listed here, I have a new one:

The type initializer for 'MyLibrary' threw an exception.

If you see something like the below in the InnerException(s)..........

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a"
```

In my case, my directory had the correct version dll. (log4net.dll in this case).

And then ... the issue was found.  Assembly redirects in the app.config.

:(

Since I had the correct version, I removed all my redirects.  Your situation may be different.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="b32731d11ce58905" />
        <codeBase version="1.2.9.0" href="log4netv1.2.9.0\log4net.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="1b44e1d426115821" />
        <codeBase version="1.2.10.0" href="log4netv1.2.10.0\log4net.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
        <codeBase version="1.2.13.0" href="log4netv1.2.13.0\log4net.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem: runs program in MS VS 2015 and triggers an exception message:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Der Typeninitialisierer für "<Module>" hat eine Ausnahme verursacht.
```

The question where source this exception?
So, I started the EXE file and displayed the exception message dialog. Answer on "debug mode" with MS VS so become more information displayed about exception.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
    Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
    Additional information: Die Datei oder Assembly "SIC, Version=19.2.6.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**************" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

I go to this reference and analyse properties
Property: "Copy Local" is on false - because before was a installed into GAC
Solution: property "Copy Local" set on true and builds new assembly and works :-)

Maybe this information helpful! So have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the app.config/Web.config has been changed in some sections.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason:
Let's say you have such a property:

```
static Dictionary<string, ComplexObject> Objects = new Dictionary<string, ComplexObject>()
{
  {"key1", new ... } // again complex initializer object
}
```

In case you use the `Objects` property inside the initializer object, such an exception will raise.
It makes sense: There is no way to **initialize** a property using its own value which is not yet been initialized!

Answer (score 0):

My case is I added comment in config file `<!---->`