# Type Initializer Exception @ Mutex

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a windows application in C#. I have my program.cs as below

```
 static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, @"Global\" + Environment.UserName);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Application.Run(new AppLogin());

            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        else
        {
            // send our Win32 message to make the currently running instance
            // jump on top of all the other windows
            MessageBox.Show("only one - 1 instance at a time");
            NativeMethods.PostMessage(
                (IntPtr)NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST,
                NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero);
        }


    }
}
```

I was able to tun the application from past several months. Suddenlty today I got an error *An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*. I have tried to debufg this but I could get any where. I have googled the exception adn alnded on  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954798/typeinitializationexception-thrown-for-program-class) which had a solution about static feilds or constructors. Now I have a `Mutex` static field and hence I have commented out all the mutex code and only had  `Application.Run(new AppLogin());`. The window now got displayed, I have 2 buttons on the window (an Accept Button and a Cancel Button). Hitting Esc on keyboard fires the Cancel Button which was fine until I go this exception, After I commented out the Mutex Code and started the  `Application.Run(new AppLogin());`this throws a `System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`exception with additional information as `Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.`. I am an Administrator on the PC I am working on and Visual Studio is running as Administrator. I can't understand this.

Comment: `TypeInitializationException` is useless on its own. You need to look at the inner exception. It is not clear to me what you are asking here; are you actually running this program in an elevated context? Remember that just because your user is admin, that doesn't mean every process you execute has admin rights. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was running the program as it was from the past few months. From past 2 days I was getting this problem - open the application in VS and start, it is immediately giving this exception, I have searched for this and found this is similar to the URL  I have listed in my post above. With mutext code commented in the Program.cs (that is shown above) the application runs and it opens the Applogin.cs.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Applogin.cs has 2 text boxes and two buttons. I click on any button it immediately throws the security exception as shown above (the inner exception is also copied). I fail to understand what is causing these exceptions for a code that has not changed from past 1 month (during which the applicaiton was running fine from visual studio).

Comment: ur app didn't change, but whatever it depended on can be change by any update. now u have to trace the actual error message, or find out what update has affected the sys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the comments to my original post above, I have searched through the solution file and found that a .manifest file was added by one of my developers.

Deleting the .manifest file ensured that the exception is no longer raised. I am not sure though on how the app.manifest file was interfering with the execution.